# Show the image of a linear transformation is in another linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $n>1$ be a natural number and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real scalar. 
Let $V$ be a subset and subspace of the vector space $P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Define $V$ as

$V=\{p\in P_n(\mathbb{R}):p(\alpha)=0\}$

Let T be function.

$T:P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto P_n(\mathbb{R}),$

$p \mapsto p\cdot(X-\alpha)$

Show T is a linear transformation and the image for T is in V.

---

I think I have managed to show T is a linear transformation. But I'm not sure how to proof the image for T is in V. I can sort of argue/see that it is in V but how do I make a proper proof?

Comment: maybe you can see it better when you write it carefully: $$T(p(X))=p(X) \cdot(X-\alpha)$$

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root for a polynomial $p(X)$, then $X-\alpha$ divides $p(X)$, that is, $p(X)=g(X)\cdot(X-\alpha)$, where $g(X)$ has one degree less than $p(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Linearity**

If $p_1,p_2\in P_{n-1}(\mathbf{R})$, then 
$$
T(p_1+p_2)=(p_1+p_2)(X-\alpha)=p_1(X-\alpha)+p_2(X-\alpha)=T(p_1)+T(p_2),
$$
and 
$$
T(cp)=(cp)(X-\alpha)=c(p(X-\alpha))=cT(p)
$$ 
for any $p\in P_{n-1}(\mathbf{R})$ and any $c\in \mathbf{R}$. You can see also that $T(0)=0$

2. **Image of $T$ is in $V$**

For any $p\in P_{n-1}(\mathbf{R})$, $T(p)(\alpha)=p\cdot(\alpha -\alpha)=0$, then the image of $T$ is in $V$.